# How to access file on Windows OS in Dockerfile

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I am trying to create a docker file to prepare an image and create a container, but I have difficulty overcoming the first step -> accessing a file on my Windows HDD.

```
FROM osrm/osrm-backend:latest

WORKDIR /opt

run osrm-extract -p /opt/foot.lua //F:/OpenStreetMapData/ecuador/foot/data/ecuador-latest.osm.pbf

run osrm-partition //F:/OpenStreetMapData/ecuador/foot/data/ecuador-latest.osm.pbf

run osrm-customize //F:/OpenStreetMapData/ecuador/foot/data/ecuador-latest.osm.pbf

run -i -p 5000:5000 --name osrm-foot osrm-routed --port 5000 --algorithm mld //F:/OpenStreetMapData/ecuador/foot/data/ecuador-latest.osm.pbf
```

But every time I am getting this error:

```
[error] Input file //F/OpenStreetMapData/ecuador/foot/data/ecuador-latest.osm.pbf not found!
```

How to pass the path to the file on my Windows machine?

Comment: You can't. Only files that are inside the "docker context" can be accessed by docker build. You need to copy your file to the same location as your `dockerfile` (or below)

Answer (score 0):

As suggested the solution is not to work with the Windows file system at all:

```
FROM osrm/osrm-backend:latest

WORKDIR /opt

ADD http://download.geofabrik.de/south-america/ecuador-latest.osm.pbf /data/

run osrm-extract -p foot.lua /data/ecuador-latest.osm.pbf

run osrm-partition /data/ecuador-latest.osm.pbf

run osrm-customize /data/ecuador-latest.osm.pbf
```